# Using a method as a variable in C++

Tags: c++, variables, methods

I'm working on an irc bot as a way to help me learn c++ and I was wondering if it is possible to use a method as a variable like this:

```
//Irc.h
public:

void *onJoin(char* sender, char* channel);
/////

//Main.cpp
void join(char* sender, char* channel)
{
    cout << sender << endl;
    cout << channel << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Irc irc(stuff);
    irc.onJoin = join;
}
```

Comment: Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). There are also [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/function.html) [variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. These variables are called functions pointers. The can write it like this:

```
void onJoin( char* sender, char * channel );

int main(void)
{
    void (*func)(char *,char *);
    func = &onJoin;
    func( "sender", "channel" );
}
```

Alternatively you can use `std::function<>` for that. The code would be the same except for the first line in `main()` which is replaced by

```
    std::function<void(char*,char*)> func;
```

This is a bit more legible in my opinion. If you use this, then don't forget to add

```
#include <functional>
```

to the top of your file. Instead of using such variables in a function, you can also use them as member variables of any `struct` or `class`.

Comment: For the first version, you can just write `auto func = &onJoin`.

Comment: for functions use either `typedef` or `auto`, otherwise they just get confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You need a pointer-to-function:

```
void* (*OnJoinFn)(char*, char*);
```

In your `Irc` class,

```
class Irc
{
public:
  OnJoinFn onJoin;
};
```

This can be assigned as you are doing above:

```
int main()
{
    Irc irc(stuff);
    irc.onJoin = join;
}
```

But I wonder, if you are just learning C++, do you really need a pointer-to-function?  pointers-to-function are certianly legal and valid, but an unusual entity and I would typically expect to use some other mechanism.  As a start, I would suggest looking in to abstract base classes:

```
class IIrc
{
public:
  virtual void* OnJoin(const char*, const char*) = 0;  // pure virtual
  virtual ~IIrc() {}; // Don't forget to implement a virtual destructor in any ABC
};

class MyIrc 
:
  public IIrc
{
public:
  void* OnJoin(const char* sender, const char* channel*)
  {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
  }
};

int main()
{
  IIrc* irc = new MyIrc;
  irc->OnJoin (...);
}
```

I've taken the liberty of introducing const correctness in `OnJoin`.

You should also consider not returning a `void*`, which bypasses most of C++'s type safety mechanisms, but a pointer to an actual object, or another interface.

Finally, using `new` (and `delete`, which is missing here, resulting in a memory leak) is poor practice.  Instead, prefer to allocate things on the stack or, if you really need dynamic allocation, use a smart pointer.

Comment: Well, I'm relearning C++. Also I know I could just use a class that inherits the irc class but I figured I would try something new.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is possible, I would suggest that you're most likely doing something wrong if you need to do this. The TYPICAL C++ way to do "we need to do this in different ways in different circumstances" is to use inheritance:

in irc.h:

```
   class ircBase
   {
     public:
      ... 
      virtual void onJoin(char *sender, char *channel) = 0;

   };
```

in ircXX.h:

```
   class ircXX: public ircBase
   {
     public:
      ... 
       virtual void onJoin(char *sender, char *channel)
       {
          cout << sender << endl;
          cout << channel << endl;
       }

   };
```

in ircYY.h:

```
   class ircYY: public ircBase
   {
     public:
      ... 
       virtual void onJoin(char *sender, char *channel)
       {
           ... do something else ... 
       }

   };
```

And then you create an object of the right kind for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a function pointer:

```
class Irc
{
    public:
        void (*on_join)(char*, char*);
    //  ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};

void join(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    Irc irc(stuff);
    irc.on_join = join;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::function` so that you can pass capturing/non-capturing lambdas:

```
#include <functional>

class Irc
{
    public:
        std::function<void (char*, char*)> on_join;
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};

int main()
{
    Irc irc(stuff);
    irc.on_join = [] (char* sender, char* channel)
    {
        std::cout << sender  << std::endl;
        std::cout << channel << std::endl;
    };
}
```